# Movies to help to brush up on conversational Italian skills?

Tags: resources, cinema

What are some good Italian language movies I could watch to help me brush up on my conversational Italian language skills?

For example, ones that have scenes of checking in at a hotel, ordering food at restaurants, navigating the railway system and airports, making bank transactions, etc.? Like an Italian version of *Planes, Trains, & Automobiles*?

There's got to be some Italian films about tourists in Italy.

Comment: Here you can find a few suggestions about Italian movies for foreign students: https://italianofacile.wordpress.com/film-italiano-facile/

Comment: Hmm.. From you're description I'm not sure if you want movies or some kind of videocourse. It's hard for a movie not made on purpose to include those subjects in a natural way (e.g. there are probably a lot of comedies where the protagonist orders food at the restaurant, but you most certainly do not want to learn from them...)

Comment: @DenisNardin What are some good videocourses?

Comment: @Geremia I don't know (I'm a native speaker, so I have little experience with language courses), but it *is* a different question than the one you're asking

Comment: @Geremia - it is not clear what’s your  level of knowkedge in Italian, anyway this http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/italiano/video_corso_di_italiano.htm as well as other courses you can easily find online may be of help.

Comment: @Gio I was advanced level over a decade ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many films to see my friend in order to brush up your conversational skills. Here are some films I recommend:

- Senza nessuna pietà (2014)
- L'uomo che ama (2016)
- Mine Vaganti (bello)
- Terra Ferma
- Io sono l'amore (elegante)
- Fuocoammare
- L'estate addosso
- Benvenuti al Sud (commedia)
- Benvenuti al Nord (commedia)
- L'industriale (mi piace molto)
- La tenerezza
- Gianni e le donne
- Benvenuto Presidente!
- Il comformista
- Palio

Comment: I removed the illegal streaming site because I don't quite think we want to become a repository of websites where you can stream movies. Moreover it is irrelevant for the actual content of the answer. I'm going to also remove the comments referring to it.

Comment: @DenisNardin I'm not going to escalate the matter, but I disagree. Your argument sounds like a slippery slope fallacy. Leaving there that web address [wasn't illegal](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/4361/5003), and I don't think it did any harm.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Other answers in the same thread say differently. The one you mentioned said the matter is not clear and “generally…”. I too would remove dubious links such as that one. Maybe this is better discussed in Meta.

Comment: Also, @Evita, welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a silly idea, but if you want to watch a movie in Italian similar to *Planes, Trains and Automobiles*, why don't you watch the [Italian dubbed version](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Un_biglietto_in_due)?

Most movies have an Italian dub, because in Italy it is very uncommon to watch subtitled movies.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but there's no similar genre film originally in Italian?

Comment: @Geremia Possibly. I don't really like that kind of comedies though, so I cannot help you much. Maybe someone else will provide other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Se vuoi qualche film di viaggio italiano puoi vedere:

*Quo vado* (2013) Checco Zalone

*Riusciranno i nostri eroi a ritrovare l'amico misteriosamente scomparso in Africa?* (1968) Ettore Scola

*Puerto Escondido* (1992) Gabriele Salvatores

*Basilicata coast to coast* (2010) Rocco Papaleo

Non si tratta di turisti, ma di italiani che viaggiano, i primi tre all'estero.

I primi due in particolare vale la pena vederli, come film in sé.

Sono tutti del genere commedia.